# i was making a web vr game with a-frame and it froze

Tags: aframe, webvr

all my tries on different ides did not work. instead, they fro-...........ze
here's my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
        <a-entity>
        <a-sphere
            position="6 1 5"
            depth="6"
            height="556"
            width="5"
            animation="
                property: roatate;
                from: 5 0 0;
                to: 0 360 0;
                dur: 2000;
                easing: nonlinear;
                loop: true"
            color="blue">
        </a-sphere>
        </a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's the [collaboration link](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/virtual-reality-with-a-frame-HAIyfK?filename=killer%20ball%2Frolling.html&collaborate=-MZE1SnJKVD7uAXEkZMh)
if you find anything i will be there.

Answer (score 2):

There are few issues with your code:

- mainly the typo **roatate** instead of **rotation**

> animation="property: roatate;...

- the **<**a-sphere**>** does not have attributes like depth, height, and width. Only **radius**. You can probably use **scale** for changing its shape.
- there is no **nonlinear** type of easing. For the full list of available easing refer to [this documentation page](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#easings)

> easing: nonlinear;

Find the working example below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a-scene>
        <a-entity>
        <a-sphere
            scale="1 2 3"
            position="6 1 5"
            animation="
                property: rotation;
                from: 5 0 0;
                to: 0 360 0;
                dur: 2000;
                easing: linear;
                loop: true"
            color="blue">
        </a-sphere>
        </a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```